# Synonyms for Hell-fire?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am seeking synonyms for the flames of Hell (hell-fire)? I cannot seem to find many at all, but I am sure there have been some numerous (perhaps poetic) coinages, especially archaic ones.

I have found the likes of "Brimstone and fire" which comes directly from the language of the bible, and also I suppose one could take creative liberties in putting something out like "nether-fire" or "Inferno's flames", but I would rather first seek if any intriguing ones have already been worked out in the English language.

Answer (score 1):

**blazes**

> b. slang. *blazes*: plural referring to the flames of hell, used in several forcible expressions, as *blue blazes, the blazes!, like blazes:* furiously, impetuously. *to (the) blazes*: to perdition, ‘to the deuce’; used in imprecations.
> [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20003) (subscription required)

Comment: Ahhh, I did not know "blazes" has a distinct connotation to Hell's fire. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of my favorites....

[Topeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tophet)

Comment: I'm not sure that a good synonym is one that would have most people looking for a dictionary.

Comment: The original asker did say this: " but I am sure there have been some numerous (perhaps poetic) coinages, especially archaic ones." Therefore, poetic or archaic are distinctly in the realm of acceptable answers.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I suggest

**fire and brimstone**

EDIT

> When people talk about fire and brimstone, they are referring to hell and how they think people are punished there after death.

[Collins]

Comment: Please could you improve this by adding references for why this is appropriate?

Comment: @user405663 thank you for the suggestion. Yes, that one I already knew, as I have been reading the KJV translation of the Holy Bible recently, and have seen it a few times over. I think if I find nothing else I will use this.

Comment: marcellothearcane: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Purgatory doesn't have anything to do with fires; it's a place of punishment or atonement, but not the same as hell.

Comment: **1** The eternal fires of Satan’s Pit/Lair/abode; **2** The flaming abode of the damned; **3** The fiery pit to which all lost souls are mercilessly condemned; **4** The demon-infested furnace of Hell; **5** The Devil’s cauldron…etc.

Comment: Thanks, Greybeard. Got to learn some cool synonyms :)

Comment: @Greybeard I would love to see some of the others that come after the “etc.”, because the ones you offered here are exquisite.